# Manage data type with Ids (Scala and haskell)

Tags: scala, haskell

I have been reading a nice article about how to manage data type or model with `id`, sometime we need the same model with `id` and the same model without `id` and the  following
[article](http://blog.originate.com/blog/2015/04/06/managing-data-classes-with-ids/) describe how to model types to handle this issue.
the below example is written in Scala and I  want its Haskell representation for better understanding

```
case class WithId[A](id: Id, model: A)

// receive data for a new user from the client
val user: User = Json.parse[User](json)

// receive data from the database
val user: WithId[User] = UserService.findByIdOrFail(userId)
```

what matters for me is the type respresenation, suppose we have the function `findByIdOrFail` and `parse` ...

Comment: Could you please update your question to make it useful for others? (Searchable title, link to the blog post...)

Comment: maybe better now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data WithId a = W { id :: Id, model :: a }

-- Receive data for a new user from the client
userId = parse json

-- Receive data from the database
user = findByIdOrFail userId
```

Comment: How would this work with regards to runtime exceptions? I think the question was about the type representation, no? I.e. `parse` would return an `Either Error User`, while `findByIdOrFail` might return an `IO (WithId User)`

Comment: both should return IO (sth), one is `IO (User)` the other is `IO (WithId User)` , the  main point is how to handle model where `id` might exits and may doesn t . for more information you can read the below article http://blog.originate.com/blog/2015/04/06/managing-data-classes-with-ids/

Comment: I disagree `parse` should not be of type `IO` unless it performs some side effect, attempting to parse a json String and returning an `Either` or a `Maybe` does not warrant the `IO` type.

Comment: It would make more sense `parse <$> getUserFromClient`, but here the code does not matter, the example is to illustrate how to model with `id`